# Hat auch im deutschen Sprachraum die Genderforschung die Verwendung von Pronomen beeinflusst?

Tags: gender-neutrality

Im Schwedischen, meiner Muttersprache, ist eine Diskussion aktuell, die von Genderforschern initiiert worden ist. Sie fordern, dass man die Pronomen „han“ bzw. „hon“, die „er“ und „sie“ entsprechen, nicht verwenden solle, weil sie nicht „genderneutral“ seien. Stattdessen solle man ein neu erfundenes Wort „hen“ verwenden. Dieses Wort haben tatsächlich auch viele, die gerne korrekt sein wollen, angenommen, vor allem in den Massenmedien.

Gibt es eine ähnliche Diskussion im Deutschen? Ich denke die Situation ist im Deutschen anders mit drei Genera, und es wäre schwieriger, eine Genderperspektive darauf zu legen, als im Schwedischen, wo wir eigentlich nur zwei Genera haben (reale und neutrum) und wo wir Femininum und Maskulinum nur bei Lebewesen unterscheiden.

Comment: Die ganze Diskussion basiert auf dem Missverständnis, dass es eine eineindeutige Abbildung von Geschlecht und Genus gäbe, was sich empirisch widerlegen lässt ("Das Mädchen hat seine Binde verloren.", "Die Person ist eine Koryphäe der Physik.", ...), aber durch beharrliche Propaganda viele Epigonen in der politischen Klasse gefunden hat. Die spontan gesprochene Sprache wird aber durch politische Absichten nicht erreicht. "Der neueste Bachmannpreisträger? Sharon Dodua Otoo!"). Es gibt politische Kreise die eine Beeinflussung versuchen, aber die Sprachforschung legt nahe, dass es ein Holzweg ist.

Comment: @user unknown. Da bin ich mit dir ganz einig. Ich möchte nur wissen ob dieses Miissverständnis in den Massenmedien irgendwie durchgesetzt ist. Wenn ich dich richtig verstehe, gibt es die Diskussion schon, und zwar "im Ernst"

Comment: Der deutsche Begriff für 'gender studies' ist 'Geschlechterforschung'  oder auch 'Genderforschung'. 'Genus' bezieht sich immer das grammatische Geschlecht.

Comment: Ich denke, es geht hier um Pronomen, nicht um Präpositionen.

Comment: @CarstenS fixed.

Comment: @DictionaricsAnonymous fixed.

Comment: Natürlich meine ich Pronomen.

Comment: Geht es denn um Genusforschung (Sprachwissenschaft) oder um Genderpolitik (m.E. keine Forschung, da nicht ergebnisoffen).

Comment: M,E nur Politik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es gibt zumindest [Vorschläge von genderneutralen Pronomen](http://annaheger.wordpress.com/pronomen/):
das Personalpronomen xier, das Possesivpronomen xieser, den Artikel und das Relativpronomen dier.

Ich habe aber noch nie eine Verwendung gesehen und gehe davon aus, das es von den wenigsten verstanden werden würde.

Was sich teilweise durchgesetzt hat, ist der Versuch einer gendergerechte Sprache mit einer Vermeidung geschlechtsspezifischer Ausdrücke ( Zum Beispiel *Studierende* statt *Student* oder *Studentin*). Siehe auch ein Beispiel eines [Leitfaden gendergerechte Sprache](http://www.frauenbeauftragte.uni-muenchen.de/genderkompetenz/sprache/index.html)

Comment: Es ist eine falsche Tatsachenbehauptung zu erklären, Studentenausweis, Studentenwerk, Student seien geschlechtsspezifische Ausdrücke.

Comment: Anfang einer Rede: "Liebe Mitglieder und Mitgliederinnen..."

Comment: Oder besser: »Liebe Mitglieder und Ohnegliederinnen …« \*wird jetzt gesteinigt\*